# Online iOS simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

Does anyone know if there exists an iOS simulator online?

I've built an iOS app that runs on iPad.  My users have asked me for a web version for their less mobile employees.  I don't want to rewrite the app in HTML.

Ideally, the simulator we use with xcode during development would be great if it's possible to run it in a web browser.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Forget, I can't imagine Apple will do something like this, they need to sell devices $$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, flight simulator is an oxymoron. But they exist, and have done well amid not-so-serious pilots.

Similarly, iOS Simulator Simulator exists too, and for the good reasons for the sincere app devs.

Visit this: https://www.pieceable.com/

Comment: Nirav - Do you have experience using pieceable?  What are your impressions?

Comment: I just featured my free app and I realize its slow though its working. Check it out: http://www.pieceable.com/view/bundle/dip/c1609/com.IphoneGameZone.NTQZ. And I did all that in 5 minutes.

Comment: If it helped even a bit, checkboxes below the answer are for a purpose. Believe me, you will get quicker help next time!

Comment: link not working bro

Answer (score 9):

There are two more iOS app players online:

- [App.io](https://app.io/)
- [Appetize.io](https://appetize.io)

Answer (score 1):

No but you can deploy your applications using [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) before you submit it to the appstore to let your customers test your code/app. (I asume that they have an iOS-device)